# Store values generated by a for-loop. JuMP/Julia

Tags: julia, julia-jump

It's amazing that the internet is totally void of this simple question (or similar). Or I'm just very bad at searching. Anyway, I simply want to store values generated by a for-loop in an array and print the array. Simple as that.

On every other language Matlab, R, Python, Java etc this is very simple. But in Julia I seem to be missing something.

```
using JuMP

# t = int64[] has also been tested
t = 0

for i in 1:5
   vector[i]
   println[vector]
end
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize `vector` and you should call the method `println` like this following way, in Julia 1.0 :

```
vector = Array{Int,1}(undef, 5)
for i in 1:5
     vector[i] = i
     println(vector[i])
end
```

Or, more quickly, with a comprehension list :

```
vector = [i for i in 1:5]
for i in 1:5
   println(vector[i])
end
```

Another possibility using `push!` method :

```
vector = []
for i in 1:5
   push!(vector, i)
   println(vector[i])
end
```